# Finding dataset for some specific years

Tags: data-request, medical

Is there any websites where I can find the health risk prediction open source tabular dataset in the year between 2015 - 2017?  Also, I need to find out some research papers that used those datasets. I know about the Google Dataset website but it seems not very resourceful.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the dataset on IEEE Dataport